# Are there any areas that become sealed off during the course of the game?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

On just about every planet, there are areas that are inaccessible until your character learns specific abilities such as wall run or force push. However, are there any areas that are initially accessible at some point, but then later become inaccessible for whatever reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places you cannot go back and explore. The starting 
 junk world(Nothing you can miss) and the last place you travel to for the finale, that place has some scanable objects that are specific to that area. Its linear so very hard to miss them.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to every area of the game except the very last area and the very first area. Both of these areas do not have any collectibles so you do not have to worry about missing any The last mission takes place in a new location (there are no collectibles, echoes or otherwise here so you don't have to worry about missing anything).  After you beat the final mission it puts you back to the point in the story just before you do that mission, though you can't play it again for whatever reason.  So the dialogue reverts back to what it was before the final mission as if it hasn't happened yet.  There a re good tutorials online for getting back to any location you don;t know how to get back to.  Just search the name of the location and there will most likely be a YouTube video that can bring you there or walk you through the surrounding areas.

Answer (score 0):

According to all of the guides I've read and my current play through the game. (I'm about 15 hours in so far) You won’t be able to access every area, open every chest, or reach every secret on your first trip to most planets. Exploration, leveling up, and backtracking with your new skills are part of the design of the game so you shouldn't worry about missing anything you won't be able to revisit later on. Also keep in mind that the map screen keeps track of all the collectibles on each planet so you should be able to tell when you've found everything on each planet.

Sources:

1. https://www.fanbyte.com/guides/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-tips-guide-11-things-the-game-doesnt-tell-you/
2. https://www.polygon.com/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-guide/2019/11/15/20963626/zeffo-chests-secrets-map-location-village-auger-hangar-monument-facility-ice-cave-tomb-crash-venator
3. https://www.ign.com/wikis/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order/Beginner's_Guide:_14_Tips_and_Tricks_for_Star_Wars_Jedi:_Fallen_Order

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I essentially say this in my first sentence. My actual question is in the second sentence: are there any areas that are eventually accessible, but for whatever reason, are NOT accessible later on in the game?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the case base on my gameplay and research online that you can miss anything in the game permanently.

Comment: That sounds like a decent answer then.

Comment: I finished the game and found that I could go back and access every area afterwards. Also, read more about it here: https://www.thegamer.com/star-wars-jedi-fallen-order-things-after-beat-end-game-checklist/